# About browsers injectors (Sonic Train)

Tags: virus, proxy, browser-extensions, browser-hijacking

I know that viruses use some ways to inject some ADs in the browsers web pages like :

1-Inject an extension

2-Inject some codes to the browser process

3-With a proxy server

4-Install an injected browser

So with one of these ways bad people can infect normal users browsers But my question is how could the Virus "Sonic Train" hijack all the Web-Browsers and he is not using any of the last four methods ?? (I mean what is the other methods)

Comment: Could you provide links to what research you have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses browser extensions. According to [MalwareTips.com](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/ads-by-sonic-train-removal/)

> Integrates into the web browser via the Sonic Train browser extension

[How-to-remove.com](https://www.how-to-remove.com/sonic-train/) has images of the extension installed in IE and Firefox. [Fixyourbrowser.com](https://www.fixyourbrowser.com/removal-instructions/remove-ads-by-sonic-train-virus-removal-guide/) also says it is done by browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

> But my question is how could the Virus "Sonic Train" hijack all the
>   Web-Browsers and he is not using any of the last four methods ?? (I
>   mean what is the other methods)

No, your assumption is wrong: actually Sonic Train installs itself as a browser extension. Most adwares (if not all of them) work as browser extensions.